# Convergence of a sequence of real convex analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convex-analysis, analytic-functions

This is a question on the convergence of a sequence of real, convex, analytic functions (it does not get better than that!):

Let $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of convex analytic functions on $\mathbb R$.

Suppose that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ (or in $\mathbb R^+$).

Is $f(x)$ analytic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: Define $f_n(x) = (x^2+1/n)^{1/2}.$ Then each $f_n$ is analytic and convex on $\mathbb R.$ Clearly $f_n(x)\to |x|$ pointwise everywhere. (A little more work shows $f_n(x)\to |x|$ uniformly on $\mathbb R.$)

Comment: Great and simple example!

Answer (score 1):

No—not even necessarily differentiable! The function $f_n(x) = \frac1n\log(1+e^{nx})$ is convex and analytic on $\Bbb R$, but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n\log(1+e^{nx}) = \begin{cases} 0, &\text{if } x\le 0, \\ x, &\text{if } x\ge0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Did you forget to divide by $n?$

Comment: @zhw Yes, thank you! Haha, I checked the limit graphically, but didn't notice the $y$-axis range was changing :D

Comment: Thanks! So I guess, the additional assumption that could make it work would be to add the constraint of  bounded derivatives.

Comment: In this and my example, the derivatives are bounded.

Comment: The derivative in 0 is actually growing with n in your example. I meant bounded with a constant K independent on n

Comment: No, check again: $|f_n'(x)|\le 1$  for all $n$ in my example.

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself poorly... I meant derivatives of all order... the first one is finite, but the next ones grows with n.