# Convergence of a sequence of real convex analytic functions with bounded derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convex-analysis, analytic-functions

This is a follow up on the discussion [Convergence of a sequence of real convex analytic functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805286/convergence-of-a-sequence-of-real-convex-analytic-functions)

Let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of convex analytic functions, *with bounded derivatives (of all orders: that it exists a constant  K independent of $n$ such that $f’(x)<K$, $f’’(x)<K$, etc...)  on  $\mathbb R$.*

Suppose that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ ( or in \mathbb R^+) (pointwise convergence)

Is it true that $f(x)$ is analytic?

NB: Clearly, this is not case without the bounded derivatives constraint (see [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805286/convergence-of-a-sequence-of-real-convex-analytic-functions)).

Comment: Think about Arzela Ascoli theorem.

Comment: Must each $f_n$ share the same bound?

Comment: The bound should be independent on $n$ (though maybe it it grows not too fast it might ok ?)